# regex works on pythex but not python2.7, finding unicode representations by regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am having a strange regex issue where my regex works on pythex, but not in python itself. I am using 2.7 right now. I want to remove all unicode instances like `\x92`, of which there are many (like `'Thomas Bradley \x93Brad\x94 Garza',`:

```
import re, requests

def purify(string):
    strange_issue = r"""\\t<td><font size=2>G<td><a href="http://facebook.com/KilledByPolice/posts/625590984135709" target=new><font size=2><center>facebook.com/KilledByPolice/posts/625590984135709\t</a><td><a href="http://www.orlandosentinel.com/news/local/lake/os-leesburg-officer-involved-shooting-20130507"""
    unicode_chars_rgx = r"[\\][x]\d+"
    unicode_matches = re.findall(unicode_chars_rgx, string)
    bad_list = [strange_issue]
    bad_list.extend(unicode_matches)
    for item in bad_list:
        string = string.replace(item, "")
    return string

name_rgx = r"(?:[<][TDtd][>])|(?:target[=]new[>])(?P<the_deceased>[A-Z].*?)[,]"

urls = {2013: "http://www.killedbypolice.net/kbp2013.html",
        2014: "http://www.killedbypolice.net/kbp2014.html",
        2015: "http://www.killedbypolice.net/" }

names_of_the_dead = []

for url in urls.values():
    response = requests.get(url)
    content = response.content
    people_killed_by_police_that_year_alone = re.findall(name_rgx, content)
    for dead_person in people_killed_by_police_that_year_alone:
        names_of_the_dead.append(purify(dead_person))

dead_americans_as_string = ", ".join(names_of_the_dead)
print("RIP, {} since 2013:\n".format(len(names_of_the_dead))) # 3085! :)
print(dead_americans_as_string)



In [95]: unicode_chars_rgx = r"[\\][x]\d+"

In [96]: testcase = "Myron De\x92Shawn May"

In [97]: x = purify(testcase)

In [98]: x
Out[98]: 'Myron De\x92Shawn May'

In [103]: match = re.match(unicode_chars_rgx, testcase)

In [104]: match
```

How can I get these `\x00` characters out? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not by trying to find things that look like "`\\x00`".

If you want to destroy the data:

```
>>> re.sub('[\x7f-\xff]', '', "Myron De\x92Shawn May")
'Myron DeShawn May'
```

More work, but tries to preserve the text as well as possible:

```
>>> import unidecode
>>> unidecode.unidecode("Myron De\x92Shawn May".decode('cp1251'))
"Myron De'Shawn May"
```

Comment: yes, just correctly fixing the unicode is what I wanted to do

Comment: Then you should probably start with asking Requests for the text instead of the content.

Comment: why 7f to ff? I see some unicodes with just 2 numbers, like 92 or 93

Comment: Because 0x92 and 0x93 are between 0x7f and 0xff inclusive.